# ReactJS I have to click twice to get my display updated

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have a mongoDB database which I connected to my app. What I want to implement is a CRUD operation using react. I created a component named "Code" which represents the data from the db.
I have an input field to add data to my db. at first, I fetch all the data from db an display it.
Since I map the data from the db to display them, for the key of each item, I am using the ._id that mongodb automatically assings to the entries. Everything works perfectly and when I open the page I can see my data from db and each component has their unique id to be rendered correctly.

There is also an input field which the user can add something to the database. The problem is when the user add something to database it will only be added to the database and I am not able to see the change in the page.

Here is my App.js which I handled the post requests and the function of adding something to db:

```js
const fetchCodesFromDB = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setDataFromDB(data);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const addCodeToDB = async (code, percentage) => {
  try {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/codes', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: code,
        percentage: percentage,
        status: 'active',
      }),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}; const fetchCodesFromDB = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setDataFromDB(data);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const addCodeToDB = async (code, percentage) => {
  try {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/codes', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: code,
        percentage: percentage,
        status: 'active',
      }),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Here is my server which I handled the post request:

```js
app.post('/api/codes', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log('Code created');
  Code.create({
    code: req.body.code,
    percentage: req.body.percentage,
    status: req.body.status,
  });
});
```

And here is I think where the problem arises:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const code = e.target.elements['discount-code'].value.toUpperCase();
  const percentage = e.target.elements['precentage'].value;

  // Check if the code already exists in the array
  const existingCode = dataFromDB.find((item) => item.code === code);

  if (existingCode) {
    // If the code already exists, display a message and don't add it to the array
    alert('Code already exists!');
  } else {
    // If the code doesn't exist, add it to the array
    addCodeToDB(code, percentage);

    // Fetch the updated array from the database
    fetchCodesFromDB();
    const newData = dataFromDB;
    setDataFromDB(newData);
  }
};
```

I fetch the data again to receive the last updated data and then set the dataFromDB the newData to update it and force it to be rerendered to see the change. The problem is it does not work at first attempt, I mean when I add something and press the add button nothing happens, but when I add another input and press the button I can see both of them in my tablle and from now on the code works and I can see the change which every new item that I add.